# Calling multiple individual thread asynchronously.But one thread stuck in loop and another thread doesn't execute

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server, threadpool

Here I have a server and client architecture server will send messages in an infinite loop. Where on the client side is a thread first which will make a connection to the server and it will also create two different threads, The first thread should read the data from the server and insert into a Queue, the second thread should read the data from the queue.

I have already tried calling second thread inside first thread to confirm the function working completely. But that's not what I want.
I have also tried to break a loop and again calling the method of inserting in recursion that also didn't work for me.

Here are the three classes which I'm using.

```
 Server.class
package threadPool.poc;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            OutputStream outputStream = s.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
            System.out.println("Server Started");
            int i = 1;
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Writing :String" + i);
                bufferedWriter.write("String " + i + "\n");
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                i++;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {

        }
    }

}
```

QueueImplementation.class

```
package threadPool.poc;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class QueueImplementation {

    public Queue<byte[]> threadQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    public void insertInQueue(byte[] value) {
        boolean isInserted = threadQueue.add(value);
        if (isInserted) {
            System.out.println("Inserted in a queue");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cannot insert");
        }

    }

    public String retriveFromQueue() {
        try {
            byte[] data = threadQueue.poll();
            if (data == null) {
                System.out.println("Doesn't have any data for threadNumber ");
                return null;
            }
            System.out.println("Data in the form of byte array for threadNumber :" + data);
            String s = new String(data, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(s);
            return s;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Client.class

```
package threadPool.poc;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client implements Runnable {

    public Client() {
        super();
    }

    static QueueImplementation queueImplementation = new QueueImplementation();

    private String threadType;

    private String message;

    private int i;

    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Starting");
        Client client = new Client("connect");
        client.run();
    }

    public Client(String threadType) {
        super();
        this.threadType = threadType;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            switch (threadType) {
            case ("connect"):
                connectServer();
                break;
            case ("insertPool"):
                insertIntoQueue();
                break;
            case ("ReadPool"):
                readMessage();
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void insertIntoQueue() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        int i = 1;
        BufferedReader reader = bufferedReader;
        System.out.println("IS buffered reader empty : " + reader);
        while (reader != null) {
            String message = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Reading message from server : " + message);
            if (message != null) {
                queueImplementation.insertInQueue(message.getBytes());
                System.out.println("Inserted in a Queue");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Null message read from server ");
            }
            i++;
        }

    }

    private void connectServer() {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            System.out.println("Client started");
            Runnable client = new Client("insertPool");
            Runnable client2 = new Client("ReadPool", i);
            /*
             * ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
             * executorService.execute(client2); executorService.execute(client);
             */
            client2.run();
            client.run();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Entered in finally");
        }
    }


    public Client(String threadType, String message) {
        super();
        this.threadType = threadType;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Client(String threadType, int i) {
        super();
        this.threadType = threadType;
        this.i = i;
    }

    private void readMessage() throws InterruptedException {

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("reading data from queue for thread : " + i);
            queueImplementation.retriveFromQueue();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    }
}
```

The output which is coming shows the thread of client 1 or client 2 stuck in a loop. Which is doesn't call another thread and it keeps waiting.

It is from server console.

```
Server Started
Writing :String1
Writing :String2
Writing :String3
Writing :String4
Writing :String5
Writing :String6
Writing :String7
Writing :String8
Writing :String9
Writing :String10
Writing :String11
Writing :String12
Writing :String13
```

It is from client console:

```
Starting
Client started
reading data from queue for thread : 0
Doesn't have any data for threadNumber 
reading data from queue for thread : 0
Doesn't have any data for threadNumber 
reading data from queue for thread : 0
Doesn't have any data for threadNumber 
reading data from queue for thread : 0
Doesn't have any data for threadNumber 
reading data from queue for thread : 0
Doesn't have any data for threadNumber 
reading data from queue for thread : 0
```

See the client result it keeps on running until I stopped.The problem here is the insert thread doesn't call.

My expected output should be like this:

the thread of read from queue method/thread call as well as in between the method/thread of inserting should also be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your client is just a runnable. It needs a backing thread to run its code.

When you call

```
client2.run();
```

the current thread enters and executes this runnable. The other client keeps there waiting for the previous one to finish, which it will not since it is in a loop.

What you need to do is wrap this runnable in a new thread and dispatch it like

```
new Thread(client2).start();
```

Comment: It is working perfectly as expected.
I want to know more deep about difference between calling directly run and starting a new Thread.

Comment: @HarshKumrawat A runnable is just a piece of code that can run on top of a thread. It by itself doesn't do anything. If you have a runnable and manually call run on it, you are just calling an ordinary method with the current thread you are on. 

In this case the thread was the main thread from the public static void main etc.. In fact if you only used  new Thread(client2).start(), the main thread picked up the second client.run(). 

If you do  new Thread(client).start() as well, there will be 3 threads. But the main will continue and finish execution, and the other 2 will run your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define what thread should do what... But you can put 1 thread doing things and the others hold... Check about synchronized keyword

https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized

Comment: I'm aware about synchronization.It allows only one thread to execute at a time and the same is happening with my case.I want to both the threads independently.